# Variable value not being cleaned/changed

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I used JSR223 PostProcessor script on a DummyRequest that should clear/change the value of a variable but somehow it is not working. It is called by a module controller which is under an IF controller which is under a Transaction controller that is called everytime during the test execution.

[image: TestPlan]

Here is the script developed to clear/change the variable value:

```
log.info("BEFORE -------------------------------------->" + "${listing_filters}");

vars.put("listing_filters", "");
//vars.remove("${listing_filters}"); //OLD ATTEMPT

log.info("AFTER --------------------------------------->" + "${listing_filters}");
```

I don't know why but the variable is not changed by the script. Below are the console output log:

```
2019-04-24 09:55:27,693 INFO o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor - Cleaning Variables: BEFORE -------------------------------------->&size=1620&discount=0&size=1620
2019-04-24 09:55:27,693 INFO o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor - Cleaning Variables: AFTER --------------------------------------->&size=1620&discount=0&size=1620
```

I also tried to remove the variable (by using vars.remove() on this PostProcessor script) and then create it again on a preProcessor script at the begging of the test flow, but it seems that once it is removed it cannot be created again.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try the below 2 options in JSR223:-

`vars.put("listing_filters","Reset")`

```
String x = vars.get("listing_filters");

if ( "completed".equals(x) ){
    vars.remove("listing_filters");
}
```

Hope this helps.